# android from app select multiple photos, but not gallery images

Tags: android, image

From the many previous posts I can now have my app launch the Intent which will allow the users to select multiple images.
But the Intent presents both Gallery Images and Photos when I want Photos only.
The Gallery Images are of no use and merely confuse the user.

So my question is how to limit the images presented to the user for selection to **Only** the Photos and **Not** the Gallery.

The code I am currently using is as follows:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.galleryimagepicker);
    lnrImages = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lnrImages);

    btnAddPhotos = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddPhotos);
    btnAddPhotos.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnSaveImages = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSaveImages);
    btnSaveImages.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnAddPhotos:
            /*Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryImagePicker.this,CustomPhotoGalleryActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);*/
            Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryImagePicker.this,CustomPhotoGalleryActivity.class);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
            break;

        case R.id.btnSaveImages:
            if(imagesPathList != null)
            {
                if(imagesPathList.size() >= 1) {
                    //Toast.makeText(GalleryImagePicker.this, imagesPathList.size() + " no of images are selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String[] stringArray = imagesPathList.toArray(new String[0]);
                    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
                        String ThisImgPath = stringArray[i];
                        String PicName = ThisImgPath;
                        if (SystemIOFile.exists(PicName)) {
                            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
                            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ThisImgPath, bmOptions);
                            Uri ThisUri = getImageUri(cntxt, bm);
                            bm = decodeBitmap(cntxt, ThisUri, bmOptions.inSampleSize);

                            Boolean HOLD = true;
                        }

                        Boolean HOLD = true;
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(GalleryImagePicker.this, imagesPathList.size() + " no of image are selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(GalleryImagePicker.this," no images are selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**  CustomPhotoGalleryActivity code:

```
public class CustomPhotoGalleryActivity extends Activity {

private GridView grdImages;
private Button btnSelect;

private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
private String[] arrPath;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private int ids[];
private int count;


/**
 * Overrides methods
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_gallery);
    grdImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdImages);
    btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }

    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    grdImages.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imagecursor.close();

    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                    cnt++;
                    selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                }
            }

            if (cnt == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select at least one image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("data", selectImages);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    super.onBackPressed();
}

/**
 * Class method
 */

/**
 * This method used to set bitmap.
 * @param iv represented ImageView 
 * @param id represented id
 */

private void setBitmap(final ImageView iv, final int id) {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            iv.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }.execute();
}


/**
 * List adapter
 * @author tasol
 */

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery_item, null);
            holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);
            holder.chkImage = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.chkImage.setId(position);
        holder.imgThumb.setId(position);
        holder.chkImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int id = cb.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        holder.imgThumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = holder.chkImage.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                    holder.chkImage.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    holder.chkImage.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            setBitmap(holder.imgThumb, ids[position]);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        holder.chkImage.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
        holder.id = position;
        return convertView;
    }
}


/**
 * Inner class
 * @author tasol
 */
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgThumb;
    CheckBox chkImage;
    int id;
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Talk to whoever wrote `CustomPhotoGalleryActivity`, then. That is the activity that you are starting, and so if that activity is not behaving the way that you want, only its developer can change it.

Comment: See above code added in EDIT.  That code came from a web posting that enabled me to get this far in the project.

Comment: You will need to invent some algorithm that determines whether an image is a photo or not, then apply that algorithm in your code. `MediaStore` has no way to know whether an image is a photo or not.